# How to override password change form in django 1.3?

Tags: django, django-admin, django-1.3

I must use django 1.3 and I have:

```
class CustomPasswordChangeForm(AdminPasswordChangeForm):

    def clean_password1(self):
        passwd = self.cleaned_data['password1']

        if passwd and len(passwd) < 6:
            raise ValidationError('password too short.')
        return passwd


class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):

    change_password_form = CustomPasswordChangeForm

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, CustomUserAdmin)
```

But in django 1.3 this not working (nothing happen - If I add my `__init__` functions to classes  I see that CustomUserAdmin is initialized but CustomPasswordChangeForm not). How to do it?

Comment: 1.3 is unsupported, you should upgrade.

Comment: I must use 1.3 in this case

Comment: That approach looks like it could work. Saying 'nothing happen' doesn't help, you'll have to do some debugging yourself. Is the custom user admin being registered? Is the admin using your custom password form? Is the custom clean method being called? You can add print or log statements to check those things, we can't.

Comment: Which URL are you trying to change the password on?